# How to use platform-specific SCSS in nativescipt-vue?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a **nativesript-vue** application using lang="scss" for styles.

### How to use platform-specific styles?

I have `app.scss` file which I import platform-specific **scss** files.

app.scss

```css
@import "~@/app.android.scss";
@import "~@/app.ios.scss";
```

Home.vue

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/app.scss";
.class {
    color:red
}
</style>
```

#### It does not render platform-specific **scss** files. But instead, it just applies last imported.

---

I have tried all methods but failed.

https://dev.to/progress/platform-specific-development-with-nativescript-dd1#customizing-styles

https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#platform-specific-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import a css file any style definitions in the imported file will overwrite style definitions with the same name from previously imported files.

*Here's how I organized my .scss files for nativescript-vue:*

@/app.android.scss

```css
@import "./styles/app-common";

/* Android-specific styles */
```

@/app.ios.scss

```css
@import "./styles/app-common";

/* iOS-specific styles */
```

@/styles/_app-common.scss

```css
@import "./app-variables";

/* Shared styles, including variables defined in app-variables */
```

@/styles/_app-variables.scss

```css
/* Variable definitions */
```

Webpack compiles all the scss into the appropriate .css files which will get loaded into your app, including the platform-specific styles.